# Problems formerly in NP but now in P

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, np

Are there any problems that used to be in NP (not NP-complete and not P) but since then have been proven to be in P? I saw [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YX40hbAHx3s) which states that people sometimes find ways of doing NP problems as quickly as P, thus proving that the problem is actually in P. Does anyone know of any examples?

Comment: This really belongs on the CS Stack Exchange, but approximate solution of linear programs is a pretty good example.

Comment: Also primality test ([2002](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test)).

Comment: I thought NP to be a proper superset of P - ?

Comment: NP is a superset of P, but it is not known whether or not it's a proper superset. That's the whole point of that P vs NP thing.